# How do you fit the menu options in a BottomAppBar in the whole bar symmetrically without getting blocked by FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomappbar

I'm trying to get 2 buttons on each side but end up getting something like this.

[image]

Is there any way to split the menu list in half? I'm currently using a `replaceMenu()` function with a `app:showAsAction="always|withText"` to get all the options displayed but somehow the text is missing.

Here's what the XML looks like:

```
<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/theme3.0"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/navigationView"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camerasvg"
    />
```

Comment: Ok, turns out that it isn't a thing yet, so you can't have 2 overflow menus (one on each side), so I went for a typical BottomNavigationView with an empty cell in the middle to put my FAB in. The downside is that there isn't going to be any inset.